# jspm + angular 1.5 + ES 5 + require

Tags: angularjs, commonjs, jspm

Is it a good idea to use JSPM with angular 1.5.x and ES 5.
this implies using commonjs module format for dependencies (require(''))
If so how would you do it?
There is not a lot of examples of this.
I was able to have a small project but i'm having trouble bundling (jspm bundle) my files.
I have an app.js file which declares the module and i have a main.controller.js file which has a controller.
in my app.js I require('angular'))
in my controller I require('app/app.js')

here is my index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app/app.js');
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController as vm">
        <div ng-bind="vm.hello"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you holding back on ES6? Really the whole point of JSPM is to take advantage of the module syntax which is an ES6 feature of course. I am sure it can be done but you are likely to end up making your life very difficult.

Take a look at Jack Franklin's examples [here](https://github.com/jackfranklin/jspm-es6-angular-example). I am pretty sure that if you follow a similar structure/method you will have some joy even without ES6.

In general though, take a look at how he structures the Angular and splits everything apart - it is a great style which allows you to expand quickly while keeping things clean and testable. Good luck.